# biblatex-chicago, backref, and crossref

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, back-referencing

Using `biblatex-chicago` with `backref=true` and `longcrossref=false`, the list of backreferences of cross-referenced items appears with the parent item, not the child. How can I make it appear with the child, or, ideally, both?

The MWE below shows the current behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,backref=true,longcrossref=false,mincrossrefs=1]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INBOOK{Leibniz1695,
author={Gottfried W. Leibniz},
crossref={Leibniz1994},
options={cmsdate=both},
origdate={1695},
pages={49–58},
title={Dialogue effectif sur la liberté de l'homme et sur l'origine du mal}
}

@BOOK{Leibniz1994,
address={Paris},
author={Gottfried W. Leibniz},
editor={Christiane Frémont},
publisher={Flammarion},
title={Système nouveau de la nature et de la communication des substances et autres textes 1690–1703},
year={1994}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Leibniz1695}
\newpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** One workaround would be to drop the crossref field from the child and add a note field with a citation of the parent in it:

```
@INBOOK{Leibniz1695,
author={Gottfried W. Leibniz},
note={In \cite[49–58]{Leibniz1994}},
options={cmsdate=both},
origdate={1695},
date={1994},
title={Dialogue effectif sur la liberté de l'homme et sur l'origine du mal}
}
```

Semantically, this is no doubt not preferable to having an explicit crossref field; and the parent does not yet inherit the backrefs.

**Edit:** In the MWE, I have inserted a `\newpage` so as to make it clear, in the printed result, that the backref shown at the parent is to the citation in the note in the child, and not, by inheritance, to the citation in the main text of the document.

Comment: Mhh, that does indeed seem to be a bug in `biblatex-chicago`. I think you should notify the author of the package, he has been very responsive to these issues in the past.

Comment: Good idea; I have now contacted the author.

Comment: The author, David Fussner, indeed replied swiftly and kindly. He will try to solve this problem more conveniently (than the workaround given) for the next release. Thanks! In the meantime, suggestions remain welcome.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug, so acknowledged by the package author

Comment: You might like to know that according to the [`biblatex-chicago` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf) this bug has been fixed in version 0.9.9f, released on 2014-08-15.

Comment: Indeed, on August 15, David Fussner notified me of this fix; being on holiday, I didn't have an occasion to test it. But now I have, and I'd like to express my gratitude to David for this improvement!